# Leaflet markercluster - cluster/uncluster toggle

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to toggle between clustered and unclustered with a leaflet MarkerClusterGroup?

I know I can disable clustering at max zoom levels using the disableClusteringAtZoom param below

```
markerHolder = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    disableClusteringAtZoom: 18,
    maxClusterRadius: 80,
    spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 1,
})
```

I would like to add a button that clusters/unclusters on click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 'uncluster' function to call per se, but you could keep both a clustered and unclustered version of your data available, and toggle between them when you click a button

```
var cluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
var marker = L.featureGroup();

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var point = points[i];
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(point[0], point[1]));
    cluster.addLayer(marker);
    markers.addLayer(marker);
}
```

see: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/393

Comment: I was thinking about this as an option. I might have 30-40k markers so I am wondering if this would weigh things down too much

Comment: you can try it, but I think you'll find that many markers will be difficult. Could work in conjunction with zoom, disable the button except at higher zoom levels.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I made a Leaflet.markercluster subplugin for such feature a while ago: [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable)

It provides extra methods on Leaflet.markercluster, including `disableClustering()` and `enableClustering()`, which enable you to uncluster / cluster programmatically (e.g. on a button click) without needing the user to zoom in/out.

See also the plugin [demo page](http://ghybs.github.io/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable/examples/mcg-freezable.html).

Of course, you should be careful whenever you call `disableClustering()`, since you may instantly load **all** your markers on map (if you are zoomed out to their full extent). If that tries loading thousands of markers, you may freeze your browser or even crash it.

> Disclaimer: I am the author of this plugin.

See also this post on StackOverflow: [With Leaflet markercluster, how can I switch between clustered and unclustered without changing zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142197/with-leaflet-markercluster-how-can-i-switch-between-clustered-and-unclustered-w)